# Developer Edition - Add a Widget

Tags: site.com, widget

I have just got developer edition of salesforce. I am looking for some guide how to add form (with input elements and submit button) on each page.
I believe the right way - is to create widget. Unfortunately I do not see "Overwiev" tab (as they say [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_widget_create.htm&language=en_US)) 
Can you help me? Did I choose a correct way? Is it possible to create widget in developer edition?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SF.SE Vladimir. Could you provide us with a screen shot and tell us a bit more about what it is that you're trying to do please? What kind of site are you creating or is this a community you're working on using site.com publisher? If the latter are you using a particular template?

Comment: Hello, here is a screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/3EEU8fH0a what I am trying to do. As I said - I have developer edition of salesforce and looking for mechanism to add submit form to any SF page (Home, Campaigns, etc)

Comment: That screen capture looks as though you're in Set-up from Create a New Application. The help link you referenced requires you to be in Site Builder. You can only add those widgets to either sites or communities pages, not to regular internal salesforce pages. That's what visualforce is for.

Comment: Thank you, crmprogdev. Are you saying that screenshot I provided is actually admistrative panel where I can create real site? And then, after I create new site I will be able to add widget there?

Comment: You can't create a widget until you create a site, that's for certain as they can only be used on sites or in communities. To me, the page looked at bit like where you create new Apps. I couldn't tell since it was only a partial screen capture that was visible without the menu bar that's normally on the left. Use the search bar from the Setup Page to find the Sites configuration menu to create one.